# Barra de rolagem em HTML

Tags: html

Bom dia gostaria de colocar uma barra de rolagem horizontal no meu código html pois não aparece na pagina, como posso fazer, segue meu código....

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
            <!-- /.box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Tipo de Lote Contábil</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><b>Plano Conta</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Carteira</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Início Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Fim Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Tipo de Lote</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">10</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                                <td align="left">Ricardo</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="left">Gabriel</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="left">Pio</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><b>Plano Conta</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Carteira</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Início Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Fim Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Tipo de Lote</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->

</ui:define>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio vaga... mas o scroll horizontal só vai aparecer na tela se a largura do filho for maior que a largura do pai... Vc poderia dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Quando a tabela e exibida no navegador os numeros relacionados ao <td align="center"><b>Tipo de Lote</b></td> não aparecem na tela por isto preciso de uma barra de rolagem horizontal pro usuário poder visualizar as informações completas.

Comment: Cara vi que vc está usando Bootstrap. Vc está usando algum CSS além do CSS do Bootstrap? Pois essa classe `content` que vc usou nessa section `<section class="content">` não existe. No Bootstrap não existe a classe `content`, acredito que ali vc na verdade colocar a classe `container` tipo  `<section class="container">` não seria isso?

Comment: Então desculpe sou um pouco leigo neste assunto, mas eu altero pra "container" e depois? Só esta alteração não faz com que a barra de rolagem apareça. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Colocando o Conteinar era pra sua tabela caber completamente dentro da tela, sem precisar de barra de rolagem, pois o conteúdo vai ficar limitado a largura do container. Mas e mesmo trocando a sua tabela ainda está "cortando" um pedaço te sugiro que edite a sua pergunta e inclusa seu CSS completo. Pois só com o que vc colocou na pergunta está difícil te dar uma resposta precisa...

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando o Bootstrap, você pode deixar somente a tabela responsiva, caso a o elemento pai seja menor e dependendo da largura da tela.

Adiciona a class em volta da tabela chamada: "table-responsive".

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <!-- /.box -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Tipo de Lote Contábil</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>XXX</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">AAAA</td>
                            </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Da uma olhada na documentação https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#always-responsive

Comment: Só uma observação... ele está usando Bootstrap 3... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar uma barra de rolagem horizontal no seu código HTML, você pode usar a propriedade CSS "overflow-x: scroll" para definir a barra de rolagem horizontal para o elemento pai da tabela.

No seu código, você pode adicionar uma classe CSS ao elemento "div" que contém a tabela e definir a propriedade "overflow-x: scroll" para essa classe.

Aqui está o código HTML atualizado com a classe CSS adicionada:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
        <!-- /.box -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Tipo de Lote Contábil</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><b>Plano Conta</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Carteira</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Início Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Fim Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Tipo de Lote</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">10</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                                <td align="left">Ricardo</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                                <td align="right">1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="left">Gabriel</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                                <td align="right">2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="left">Pio</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                                <td align="right">3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><b>Plano Conta</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Carteira</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Início Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Dt. Fim Vigência</b></td>
                                <td align="center"><b>Tipo de Lote</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

</ui:define>

E aqui está o código CSS que você pode adicionar ao seu arquivo CSS para estilizar a tabela:

```
    .table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Creio que isso possa te ajuda man, eu so peguei seu codigo e testei, porem faça como o cara disse acima sobre a biblioteca Bootstrap